# How can I join my baked textures into a new material [cycles]

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, baking, uv-image-editor

I have two cube objects, both with a specific material and with a texture. I want to join the objects together so I do that and then I make a new material called 'Bake'. I also make another UVMap with the same name. I make a lightmap pack of the joined object and after selecting the 'Bake' image texture of the 'Bake' material, it was finally time to bake...

The bake texture resulted in black but the cubes got baked onto their own materials.. 
**What I'm trying to do is that both cubes get baked into the 'Bake' material/texture**

*There are more then 2 images that I want to share so [here](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNj5HQMEiQmTL7mul-Gqnw1VltB1_rqtXhoWqjNmldLn6uwy6_royXTZaPWMuS6qQ?key=NGhFTWhRQ2NXUDQwU2N1NzczZVVySUZKcEY3dTN3) is a link to that*

Comment: You don't bake onto a material, but you bake onto a texture. Add a texture node in your material, set a texture to it. Don't connect it to anything but **this node needs to be selected** so that Cycles knows where to bake. Here as you have two materials, set this texture node in both materials. And lower the margin as your UV map parts are very close to each other

Comment: For the new material... once the bake done, simply reuse the baked texture in this new material (assigned to a copy of your mesh, for instance, after you have removed the other materials)